# Mongo: Order by item presence in array field, then by timestamp field

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Let me be clear upfront that I'll gladly accept links to answers to this question if it's been made before. I'm not sure how to phrase it succintly to look for it in search engines, sorry.

I have a blog posts collection called *articles.* Those articles have associated tags stored in an array field (called `tags`.) They also have a post timestamp field (called `on`.)

So the collection looks like this:

```
[
    {
        _id: '526dd103f00c470200000001',
        title: 'Lorem ipsum 1.',
        body: 'Dolor sit amet 1.',
        tags: ['lorem', 'ipsum'],
        on: 1000
    },
    {
        _id: '526fda069909000200000002',
        title: 'Lorem ipsum 2.',
        body: 'Dolor sit amet 2.',
        tags: ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'pinned'],
        on: 2000
    },
    {
        _id: '527366a11f58a90200000001',
        title: 'Lorem ipsum 3.',
        body: 'Dolor sit amet 3.',
        tags: ['lorem', 'ipsum'],
        on: 3000
    },
    // Etc.
]
```

I want articles to be ordered by date (descending,) but I also want articles containing the tag "pinned" to always appear at the top. So the result set should look like this:

```
[
    {
        _id: '526fda069909000200000002',
        title: 'Lorem ipsum 2.',
        body: 'Dolor sit amet 2.',
        tags: ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'pinned'],
        on: 2000
    },
    {
        _id: '527366a11f58a90200000001',
        title: 'Lorem ipsum 3.',
        body: 'Dolor sit amet 3.',
        tags: ['lorem', 'ipsum'],
        on: 3000
    },
    {
        _id: '526dd103f00c470200000001',
        title: 'Lorem ipsum 1.',
        body: 'Dolor sit amet 1.',
        tags: ['lorem', 'ipsum'],
        on: 1000
    }
    // Etc.
]
```

What I want to do is use Mongo aggregrations, map-reduce, or something similar to order the result set inside the database itself.

I could just make 2 queries (one including only pinned posts, another including only unpinned posts, both ordered by date) and join them using JavaScript (the server is nodejs,) but would like to know the better ways.

*P.S.: I'm using the node-mongodb-native driver.*

Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your answer with a sample of a document or two. Then we have something to work with.

Comment: Just added it, @NeilLunn.

Comment: Is that supposed to have a date field there as well? You say you want to sort. Can you add them please.

Comment: The `on` field is supposed to be a timestamp field. I'm aware there's a specialized data type for dates, but my schema currently just uses a timestamp.

Comment: Looks like this answers my question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22108015/180581.

Comment: I don't see your comments unless you tag me. You have an answer anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowing from another answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22108015/180581):

One way to achieve this using Mongo's [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) is to first [unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) all articles by tag, then [project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) them to create an `is_pinned: true` field in all unwound documents that have tag "pinned", then [group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) them back together by ID, like this:

```
db.articles.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: '$tags'
    },
    {
        $project:
        {
            title: 1,
            body: 1,
            tags: 1,
            on: 1,
            is_pinned: { $eq: ['$tags', 'pinned'] }
        }
    },
```

In order to group back identical documents, we can use [$first](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) on each field, [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) on the unwound field to recreate the original array, and [$max](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) or [$sum](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to aggregate `is_pinned` ($max works just fine and as expected with booleans, so I prefer it):

```
    {
        $group:
        {
            _id: '$_id',
            title: { $first: '$title' },
            body: { $first: '$body' },
            tags: { $push: '$tags' },
            on: { $first: '$on' },
            is_pinned: { $max: '$is_pinned' }
        }
    },
```

Then, finally, we can [sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) them using `is_pinned` and `on`:

```
    {
        $sort:
        {
            is_pinned: -1,
            on: -1
        }
    }
])
```

Something similar is obviously also possible with map-reduce, but it feels like a bit of an overkill, and I'd expect the aggregation pipeline to become heavily optimized in the future, in a way that doing a manual map-reduce also feels... wrong.

Map-reduce may be necessary if you hit the aggregation pipeline / grouping limitations. At the time of this answer (MongoDB 2.4.9,) the [aggregation pipeline documentation states](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/):

> Important: The result of aggregation pipeline is a document and is subject to the BSON Document size limit, which is currently 16 megabytes.

Additionally, [$group documentation states](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

> Warning: The aggregation system currently stores $group operations in memory, which may cause problems when processing a larger number of groups.

I'm not sure how that applies to map-reduce, but currently map-reduce might be a way to work around these potential problems.

Since those are not a problem to me, the solution presented here seems good enough.

Comment: Just realized unwinding a post with no tags will cause the document to be dropped from the pipeline. I'm not sure how to solve this just yet. Will update when I find out.

Comment: With MongoDB 3.2 you can preserve empty or null arrays:

`{ "$unwind": {
            "path": "$tags",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    } }`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job, using aggregate:

```js
db.ipsum.aggregate([

    {$unwind: "$tags" },

    {$project: { 
        _id: "$_id",
        title: "$title",
        body: "$body",
        on: "$on",
       "tags": "$tags",
       weight: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$tags", "fixed"]}, 1, 0]} 
    }},

    {$group: {
        _id: { 
            _id: "$_id",
            title: "$title",
            body: "$body",
            on: "$on"
        },
        tags: {$push: "$tags"},
        weight: {$sum: "$weight"}
    }},

   {$sort: { weight: -1, "_id.on": -1 }},

   {$project: { 
       _id: 0,
       _id: "$_id._id",
       title: "$_id.title",
       body: "$_id.body",
       on: "$_id.on",
       tags: "$tags" 
    }}

])
```

So the main part is using $cond to assign a weight to the item you want at the top of your sort, then sort appropriately.

Comment: Isn't that $group unnecessarily heavy? I think _id should be just '$_id', otherwise $group will compare titles, bodies, and on fields when grouping, too, when _id should be enough. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @n2liquid-GuilhermeVieira Not if you want the original document back